# C function to find the mode in an array printing off an array full of 0's

Tags: c, function, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a function that returns the mode(s) of a sorted array and it just isn't working right. It works perfectly fine when there's no modes however whenever there are modes I get:

Mode(s): < 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000 >

Here's the function

```
void findMode(double * a, unsigned int size)
{
    double number = a[0]; //Used to to compare values in the array to see if they're similar
    int count = 1; //Keeps track of number of occurences for each number
    int max = 1; //Keeps track of max number of occurences found for each number
    int uniqueNum = 1; //Keeps track of how many unique values in the array
    int maxCount = 1; //Counts how many set's of numbers occur the max ammount of times
    int elementNum = 0; //Keeps track of element number in mode array

    for (unsigned i = 1; i < size; ++i)//loop to determine how many modes and unique numbers there are
    {
        if (number == a[i])
        {
            ++count; //if the numbers the two numbers compared are the same, count is increased by 1
        }
        else
        {
            if (count == max)
            {
                ++maxCount; //Keeps track of how many modes are in the array
            }
            if (count > max)
            {
                //If the two numbers compared are not the same and the count of the previous "set" of similar numbers is higher than the current max count, max is equal to the new count
                max = count;
                maxCount = 1; //Reset the max count if a new max is found
            }
            //Count is set back to 1 as we are counting a different number
            count = 1;
            number = a[i];
            ++uniqueNum; //Unique number variable gets incremented
        }
    }

    count = 1; //sets count back to 1 for next loop

    if ((double)size / max != uniqueNum)
    {
        double mode[sizeof((double)maxCount)]; //makes the mode array the right size to store all the modes
        for (unsigned i = 1; i < size; ++i)//loop to determine what the modes are
        {
            if (number == a[i])
            {
                ++count; //if the numbers the two numbers compared are the same, count is increased by 1
            }
            else
            {
                if (count == max)
                {
                    mode[elementNum] = a[i];
                    ++elementNum;
                }
                //Count is set back to 1 as we are counting a different number
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        printf("\nMode: {");
        for (int i = 0; i <= (sizeof(mode) / sizeof(mode[0])); ++i)
        {
            printf(" %.3lf ", &mode[i]);
        }
        printf("}");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNo mode");
    }
}
```

For all I know the entire function could be garbage and I'd need to start over, or it could just be 1 tiny mistake.

Comment: What is this `sizeof((double)maxCount)`?

Comment: maxCount tracks how many times the mode appears in the array, so I'm setting the array that holds the modes to that size.

Comment: `sizeof((double)maxCount)` is the same as `sizeof(double)` which is `8` on most systems.

Comment: So how should I be going about it?

Comment: `double mode[maxCount]` will create an array with `maxCount` elements. I'd be surprised if that's the only problem. You probably want to print out `uniqueNum` and `maxCount` after the first loop to make sure you got sensible results. Better yet, step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: I do that and it says "Expression must be a constant value.

I've checked the unqiueNum and maxCount values already, they're fine

Comment: Oh, the compiler doesn't support VLAs. So `double *mode = malloc(maxCount * sizeof(double));` and then use `mode` as if it was an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, the mode value is the value in a set of numbers that has the most occurrence. There are some minor issues with your code that prevent it from behaving as you expect.

First as mentioned in the comments, the modes arrays is always defined as 8 since sizeof((double)maxCount) always evaluates to 8 bytes on most systems (platform dependant). It should be:

```
double modes[maxCount];
```

Note: To avoid compile warnings and errors, you may need to compile it with -std=c99 if you're using gcc.

Just before the second for loop, you forgot to re-assign the variable number to the first element of the array "a".

As such, the second for loop is only comparing the variable "number" (which is assigned a value from "a" as a result of the last for loop) with every other number in "a", hence it is not actually finding the mode.

Now in your second for loop you forgot to refresh the variable "number" to the non-equal element in array "a" when you found that number != a[i].

So basically, the for loops of the function should appear something like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < size; i++)//loop to determine how many modes and unique numbers there are
{
    if (number == a[i])
    {
        ++count; //if the numbers the two numbers compared are the same, count is increased by 1
    }
    else
    {
        if (count == max)
        {
            printf("inside. a = %.3lf\n", a[i]);
            ++maxCount; //Keeps track of how many modes are in the array
        }
        if (count > max)
        {
            printf("Reset. a = %.3lf\n", a[i]);
            //If the two numbers compared are not the same and the count of the previous "set" of similar numbers is higher than the current max count, max is equal to the new count
            max = count;
            maxCount = 1; //Reset the max count if a new max is found
        }
        //Count is set back to 1 as we are counting a different number
        count = 1;
        number = a[i];
        ++uniqueNum; //Unique number variable gets incremented
    }
    printf("a = %.3lf count = %d and max = %d\n", a[i], count, max);
}

if (count == max){ // handle the case where the lat couple of numbers are the same e.g {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0};
    ++maxCount;
}

count = 1; //sets count back to 1 for next loop

// printf("max = %d\n", max);

if ((double) (size / max) != ((double)uniqueNum))
{
    double mode[maxCount]; //makes the mode array the right size to store all the modes
    number = a[0];
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < size; i++)//loop to determine what the modes are
    {
        if (number == a[i])
        {
            ++count; //if the numbers the two numbers compared are the same, count is increased by 1
        }
        else
        {
            if (count == max)
            {
                mode[elementNum++] = number;
            }
            //Count is set back to 1 as we are counting a different number
            count = 1;
            number = a[i];
        }
    }

    if (count == max){
        mode[elementNum++] = number;
    }

    printf("\nMode: {");
    for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
    {
        printf(" %.3lf ", mode[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\nNo mode");
}
```

Note: This might not be fully what you're after but it should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: As I've said before I get an error when I try to do the give a size to the mode array like you said.

Could I just use malloc? Other people have said it'll work

Comment: Using malloc() should be fine just don't forget to call free() after.

Comment: Am I wanting to call free() at the end of the function or program?

Comment: I would call free at the end of the function.

Comment: You have done gods works today my friend, I've been spending days trying to figure this out

Comment: But yes, it still needs work, it keeps returning a value of < 2.000 > if there's a mode regardless of what the mode is and how many there are